# How to require user login with Social-auth?

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm using Facebook login with Social-Auth, but how I can require a user to be logged in to access some view/template?
Can I use user_required the same as with User app from django?

Comment: Have you tried using `login_required` decorator?

Answer (score 1):

Django-social-auth extends the built in authentication system. Simply use @login_required as a decorator, or whatever normal Django mechanism you prefer.